# Chamar uma view em uma subpasta

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Olá, pessoal.

Eu criei uma view, dentro de uma subpasta como este exemplo:

Views
   |
   Home
      |
      MinhaSubpasta
          MyView.cshtml

No controlador, eu tenho o seguinte método que deverá chamar essa view na subpasta:

```
    private ActionResult MinhaView()
    {
        return View("??????"); // <= tem que chamar a view que está na subpasta
    }
```

Eu não sei como chamar essa view na minha subpasta.
Algum colega poderia me ajudar nesta questão?

Abraços
Hugo

Comment: Essa controller corresponde as views da pasta Home?HomeController?

Comment: Sim, o método está na HomeController. Mas eu fiz isso por enquanto, para exemplificar e postar minha questão. Na realidade, eu farei isso em outro controller personalizado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
return View("~/MinhaSubpasta/MyView.cshtml");
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Deu o seguinte erro:

Comment: The view '~/MinhaSubpasta/MyView.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/MinhaSubpasta/MyView.cshtml

Comment: O nome da pasta e da view é esse mesmo? MinhaSubpasta e MyView? Tem que estar escrito exatamente como no diretório.